# Healthcare Finder PlanSummaryBenefitURL Error

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I am trying to use the PlanSummaryBenefitURL when i call the [Finder API](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0). I can HTTP POST information fine from the API but when I try and open the PlanSummaryBenefitURL link I get an error message.

Example:

```
https://hiosgateway.cms.gov/RBIS-API/v11.0/REST/getSBCReportFile?planId=94073WI0240199&fileType=pdf

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  <soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring><faultactor>https://hiosgateway.cms.gov/RBIS-API/v11.0/REST/getSBCReportFile?planId=94073WI0240199&fileType=pdf</faultactor><detail><l7:policyResult status="Error in Assertion Processing"/></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I cannot access this link on my android phone either. I get this error message:
[image]

Is there a solution to this issue and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but there was an issue with the service around that time. I can load the URL you provided and get back an SBC.

In Chrome on Android I do get a message asking me to set device security for certificate, but hitting cancel will still download the PDF.